# How can I quickly tell whether I own a different version of the same game on Steam?

Tags: steam

I have way too many Steam games.  As a result I don't always remember which ones I have when browsing their fantastical sales, and more than once I've tried to check out only to have it warn me that I already own the game and am wasting my time.

Recently I noticed that on the game pages they now tell you whether or not you own the game.  This is excellent and is sure to save me some time.  There's one problem though: It doesn't tell me whether I own a different version of the same game.  For example I own the standard Civilization 5 edition, and on the page for the GOTY edition it doesn't tell me that I own the other version.  (It doesn't warn you at checkout either.)

I've resorted to opening a separate browser tab to my All Games list and manually typing in part of the title to check whether I have the game.  Is there something quicker than this?  Ideally I would just go to the game page and it would say right there that I own a different version of it, just like the same-version warning, but I'm open to other solutions.

Comment: Given that GOTY usually includes all the DLC, it would be interesting if the reverse is true.  Would owning GOTY flag the standard as owned?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you don't even get a warning at checkout means Steam considers them different games. Therefore there is no way it would tell you you own it already.

Answer (score 2):

I use a Chrome extension called [Enhanced Steam](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/) (no affiliation). It basically provides small UI improvements to Steam store, such as highlighting games you already own. I am unsure whether or not it differentiates between different versions of the same game.

I tried searching for Civilization V (which I already own) but cannot find the GOTY version you mention. However I know it will tell me if I try to buy a DLC, that I already bought in a different bundle or something – or if I already own some items in a bundle, it will tell me if I still save money, compared to buy the missing items separately.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer steam does not for some games differentiate between goty / std etc, if you have the games all within steam you may not be aware that you can create custom categories and your library will list all items in a category together.

this at least will reduce the list that your looking through, I have categories I have setup for RTS, FPS, etc :)